# Spark Code Debugging in Eclipse

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am debugging the Spark Code in Eclipse. The problems I am facing are as follows:

1. I am creating JSON object inside `RDD` but in `logger.info`/`println`, it
   is not printing anything on console.
2. It is printing the information of `logger.info("Record stream count " + rdd.count)` and other `RDD` method but not printing anything for the methods that I am calling in `RDD`.
3. How to stop spark application, once started. Mine is Scala code where I am taking the input from Spark DStream and reading from `.txt` file for setting up the environment locally.

Please let me know for any additional questions/clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About first and second point of your question,
But first, is your application running in Cluster mode? If so, quoting http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

> However, in cluster mode, the output to `stdout` being called by the
>   executors is now writing to the executor's `stdout` instead, not the one
>   on the driver, so `stdout` on the driver won’t show these! To print all
>   elements on the driver, one can use the `collect()` method to first
>   bring the `RDD` to the driver node thus: `rdd.collect().foreach(println)`.

About your third point, you can stop your Spark application by providing master and driver ID in following

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill <master url> <driver ID>
```